# Get a valid path with random directory name from a text file

Tags: linux, grep, awk

How to to get the valid path from a string?

For example I have the following text in `file.txt` that will always generate with a random path using the following patern:

```
Some error occurred. rerun the script with "-d" option and check the output and logfile: /tmp/du_resp_16929.
```

The path `/tmp/du_resp_XXXXX` has the random number at the end (marked as XXXXX). What is the best way to obtain the path?

I know how to use awk like below to get the end of string but sometimes the path might be in the middle or at the beginning.

```
awk ‘{print $(NF)}’ file.txt | sed 's/\.$//'
```

output:

```
/tmp/du_resp_16929
```

So, I don't think the above is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep with option `-oP` does the job wih regex `/tmp/du_resp_\d+`.
Where `\d+` means 1 or more digits.

```bash
 grep -oP '/tmp/du_resp_\d+' file.txt
/tmp/du_resp_16929
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, something that works on your example,
it might need adjustment for other forms of content:

```
$ sed < file.txt -re 's,^.* (/tmp/[^ .]+).*,\1,'
/tmp/du_resp_16929
```

Depending on how you generate the random part (XXXXX) you might get not only numbers but also other characters, `[^ .]` looks up the next space or `.` character after `/tmp/` and stops including characters there.

This regex will work for more random names e.g. created by `mktemp`

```
$ for ((i=1; i<5 ; i++)) ; do mktemp -u /tmp/du_resp_XXXXX ; done
/tmp/du_resp_0Mdw6
/tmp/du_resp_D1xlI
/tmp/du_resp_EjsZU
/tmp/du_resp_cYWB9

$
```

Answer (score 1):

The following command will isolate substrings matching your `/tmp/du_resp_XXXXX` pattern:

```
grep -Eo '/tmp/du_resp_[0123456789]{5}'
```

Notes:

- Tested with GNU `grep` 3.7.
- If there are many matches in a line of input then you will get each match in a separate line of output.
- `du_resp_123456` will give you `du_resp_12345`. Replace `{5}` with `{5,}` to match 5 or more digits.
- `[0123456789]` is a straightforward pattern to match an ASCII digit. `[0-9]`, `[[:digit:]]` or `\d` [are not equivalent to it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414230/108618). Use the one you really want.

Comment: `grep -Eo '/tmp/du_resp_[0-9]{5}'`

Comment: @Hannu There is no guarantee `[0-9]` in the OP's locale is equivalent to `[0123456789]` I want.

Comment: THAT would be odd, IMO. Example?

Comment: @Hannu Check this in *your* locale: `echo '0123456789 ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩ ۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹ ߀߁߂߃߄߅߆߇߈߉ ०१२३४५६७८९' | grep -o '[0-9]\+'` . You may be surprised.

Comment: Ahh... ;-) "outlandish" (other character sets) which does not use arabic numerals, and the difference from `[0123456789]` to `[0-9]` is what? ;-)  i.e. i cannot get it to be different.

Comment: @Hannu `[0123456789]` matches exactly what it says, no surprises. This is what I want in my answer.

Comment: Well, I would be very surprised if `[0-9]` was ambiguous in that regard. :-)

Comment: `[0-9]` is not ambiguous if one knows the locale. I don't know the OP's locale. In many locales `[0-9]` matches more than `[0123456789]` matches. The point is I don't want to match more.